# computed property as @Published in ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui

Is there any way to define computed property as @Published property in ObservableObject?

I know it is possible in the case of @Binding.

```
var computedValue: Binding<Double> { Binding (
    get: {
        self.value + 3.0
    },
    set: { _ in }
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `willSet` for Published values.

```
@Published var myVar : Bool = false {
    willSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
        print("Will set to new variable, which is \(newValue)")
    }
}
```

- you can access `newValue` for the new Value inside the willSet function and your variable